# Using slack-ruby-bot

Tags: ruby, slack-api

I am trying to get to grips with the `slack-ruby-bot` gem. Looking at the examples I can match on text and then send back a response

```
match /^Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?$/ do |client, data, match|
  client.say(channel: data.channel, text: "text here")
end
```

To get a response from the bot I would just write `Is this bike stolen 123456?` and I would get `text here` returned.

What I want to achieve though is for a response only if I do `@bot Is this bike stolen 123456?`, so I have to specifically ask the bot.

It would also be great to show some typing text whilst the response is being put together.

Are there any examples to look at for inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

You're code is already most of the way there, I think.

```
match /^Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?$/ do |client, data, match|
  client.say(channel: data.channel, text: "text here")
end
```

I think all you need to do is add the `@bot` string to the regex -

```
/^@bot Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?$/
```

If you want to use this will all commands, you can make a wrapper method for the regex:

```
def bot_regex(rest_of_regex)
  /^@bot #{rest_of_regex}$/
end

regex = bot_regex "Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?"
match regex do |client, data, match| # etc
```

It might also be helpful to wrap the regex match catcher in a method:

```
def regex_matcher(name)
  "(?<#{name}>\w*)"
end

matcher = regex_matcher("frame_number")
regex = bot_regex "Is this bike stolen #{matcher}\?"
```